# Firebase sort by alphabetical order

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

is possible to sort the database list by alphabetical order?
I tried the sortby() function, but it didn't work properly

```
var snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Locations').where(
            "category", "==", type).orderBy('name','desc').get();
```

for example in the database:
1- name:chicken
2- name:pig
3- name:duck

after I sort by name, the order should be
chicken, duck, pig

Here is how the database look, and the result after I ran my code.
[image: database]

[image: result]

Here is my full code:

```
export default function filtercat(type,sortformat){

    var locList = []

    const filterbytype = async() =>{

        if (sortformat == 'rating'){

             // will filter by the type of location, and then sort by rating
        var snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Locations').where(
            "category", "==", type).orderBy('rating','desc').get();
        
        // this is for All category, it will display all locations
        if (type == 'All'){
            var snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Locations').orderBy('rating','desc').get()
        }
        if (snapshot.empty){
            console.log('No matching documents');
            return;
        }
        
        snapshot.forEach(doc=> {
            locList.push(doc.data());
        })
        
        }

        if (sortformat == 'name'){

            // will filter by the type of location, and then sort by alphab
        var snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Locations').where(
            "category", "==", type).orderBy('name','asce').get();
        // this is for All category, it will display all locations
        if (type == 'All'){
            var snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Locations').orderBy('name','desc').get()
        }
        if (snapshot.empty){
            console.log('No matching documents');
            return;
        }
        
        snapshot.forEach(doc=> {
            locList.push(doc.data());
        })
        }
       
        
    }
    
    return filterbytype().then(()=>{
        console.log(locList)
        return locList;
    })
    // filterbytype()
}
```

The part having issue is when the sortformat is name.

Here is the indexes in firebase[image: Index]

Comment: It is hard to say why your code didn't work. Can you edit your question to show: 1) a screenshot of the documents you're querying from the Firebase console? 2) the code that processes the `snapshot` and prints the (faulty) result?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, I just updated my question, as you can see, the result didn't sort the name correctly.

Comment: Thanks for that update. I'm still missing the code for #2, which unfortunately may be relevant. I also immediately noticed that you log output shows the `rating` as a number, but in the screenshot of the database it is stored as a string. Storing numbers as strings is a common cause of sorting problems, as strings are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, I just updated my full code. the sorting by rating is working properly, but when sorting by alphabetic order doesn't work. looks like is going from Z to A instead of A to Z

Comment: That would match with this order clause: `orderBy('rating','desc')`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Can you show the index you have created in Firestore?

Comment: @Prabir HI, I just updated the picture of indexes

Comment: Everything looks perfect. It is strange how you are getting data in reverse order. I would suggest you raise a support ticket with Google Cloud Platform Support to investigate the issue in detail and find a root cause. If you don’t have a valid support package you may raise a Free [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) ticket.

Answer (score 0):

There are few limitations with firebase `where` and `orderBy`

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your
> first ordering must be on the same field:

So in your case you are having `where` condition on `category` field and `orderBy` on `name` so according to firebase document, it will not work.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) is the reference document

Comment: Hi Ravi, But when I sort by the rating it works fine. `where("category", "==", type).orderBy('rating','desc').get();` this way it will sort by the higher rating to lower.  can you give me a hint of how to sort by character alphab

Comment: strange, because it should not work with rating as well, can you please verify if rating is actually being sorted or data in datastore itself is in sorted format for rating. Because when I had this same issue, I have prioritise the things like I have done where clause in firestore query and have done sorting in local array.

Comment: yeah it does work, but I need to create index in the firebase first.